# How do you use a Budapest 5/30 travelcard?

Tags: public-transport, tickets, budapest

When looking over the [WikiVoyage Budapest page of public transport tickets](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Budapest#Tickets_and_passes), I spotted an interesting looking ticket for a trip which sees me needing to travel quite a bit on two weekends, but not the week inbetween:

> **5/30 travel card:** 5 one-day travel cards. This booklet of 5 slips is valid for 30 days. Before beginning a 24 hour period of travel, mark the date and time with pen on an unused slip. Do not tear even used slips out of the booklet.

I also found [something about it on the English BKK website](http://www.bkk.hu/en/prices/530-bkk-24-hour-travelcard/), but I'm not sure I've fully understood it. Given the warnings on the [WikiVoyage page](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Budapest#Tickets_and_passes) about ticket inspectors showing no lenience to confused tourists, I don't want to get it wrong!

Assuming I can find somewhere to sell me one of these on arrival:

- Am I correct in thinking it offers unlimited use of trams, buses and metros, with unlimited transfers, for 24 hours after each ticket starts?
- What must I (and mustn't I) write and where whenever I want to start a new 24 hours?
- Do I need to do any validating of the ticket when using it, or is writing in enough?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This travelcard is valid for all trams and buses (including the night buses) in Budapest and some close suburbs (including the airport), on the HÉV suburban lines within the city limits (a separate suburban network that's pretty much like the metro), as well as on the BKK ferry. It isn't valid on the main suburban trains (not operated by BKK) nor on the funicular.

The 5/30 card is basically a booklet of five 24-hour cards (note that you must not detach them from the booklet: if even one page is torn out, the booklet is invalid). The sales desk marks the valid 30-day period (if you get it from a machine, it should ask you for the starting date; if you get it from a clerk, they might assume the current day if you don't say anything). Each card is valid 24 hours from the date indicated, e.g. you can use it on one afternoon and the following morning.

You indicate the date for each page by marking the start date and time at the back. I'm pretty sure you don't need to stamp it (I don't think the card would even fit in the validator). Here's a picture showing the back of a page, from a [forum in Russian](http://ftour.otzyv.ru/read.php?id=75356&p=400#4719456):

[image: Budapest 5/30 travelcard]